# Not getting results with $near/$geoNear - GeoJSON in nested location object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, geojson

I'm trying to filter based on **$near**/**$geoNear** provide by MongoDB and have Apollo GraphQL backend.
But unable to do it.

Here is my object:

```
{
  firstName:"Steve",
  lastName:"Jobs",
  location:{
    name:"Cupertino, CA",
    geoCords:{
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [72.0000,54.9999]
    },
    lat: 54.9999,
    lng: 72.0000
  }
}
```

Here as you can see **geoCords** is the GeoJSON object.

> **Quick Question/Clarification**:
>
> Is GeoJSON, a regular JSON object that should have type(String) and coordinates(Array [lng, lat]) ? Or do we need to insert GeoJSON in a different way?

---

**How am I setting the index?**

I have set the index in the following way:

`db.collection.createIndex({ geoCords: '2dsphere' });` also have tried `db.collection.createIndex({ 'location.geoCords': '2dsphere' });`

When I try to query it/find it, I'm not getting the results.

**Here is my query:**

```
db.collection.find({
 location.geoCords: {
   $near:{
     $geometry:{
      type:'Point',
      coordinates: [72.0,56.0]
     }
   }
 }
})
```